# Selective NAT of the packets with iptables

Tags: iptables

How can I make iptables NAT all packets, except those, that have a target address from 192.168.254.0/24 subnet?

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you well, this should be fairly easy using the option `-d` with negation. For example, a rule like this one:

```
$ iptables -A POSTROUTING ! -d 192.168.254.0/24 -j SNAT --to-source new_source_ip
```

Of course, you can change the rule according to your needs. This changes the source IP of all packets destined to any destination except the indicated subnet.

Comment: Found this one and it's very useful for IPv4 for me. I have a main router which doesn't know how to handle static routes correctly for the public Internet, but I also want some sort of limited LAN flexibility. The router forwards packets correctly when it's LAN to LAN but if WAN is involved I believe the router fails to NAT the packets correctly unless it's from its own LAN. So doing this I seem to be able to avoid the bug without losing the ability to directly connect to VMs.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion following order of iptables commands would work:

```
1. iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.254.0/24 -o eth0 -j RETURN
2. iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 0.0.0.0/0 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

rule 1 will match your network and won't MASQUERADE it
rule 2 will masquerade all but generally it's not good idea to give 0.0.0.0 wildcard (I'm not even sure if it will work). You should selectively add all networks that you want to masquerade and rest just won't be masqueraded.

Comment: You're offering something that filters by source address, not by destination address as the question asks. The other answer does exactly that.